# Numeric pad dosent work with my calculator

Tags: javascript, html, css

I just finish a calculator for my collegue but I would like use a numeric pad with it.
My problem is simple ! which javascript function do I need to connect numeric pad with my calculator ?

I am a beginner dev and it's my code !

Thank you for you help !

```js
/*
** operation functions
*/

var dropdown = document.querySelector('material-dropdown');
var dropdownMenu = document.querySelectorAll('material-dropdown-menu');
var items = document.querySelectorAll('material-dropdown div')

var dropdown = {
  // storage for currentry selected item
  selected: '',

  select: function() {
    dropdown.selected = this.innerHTML;
  },

  close: function(evt) {
    target.setAttribute('selected', dropdown.selected);
    target.removeAttribute('state');
    target.querySelector('#label').innerHTML = dropdown.selected;
  },
  
  open: function(target) {
    target.setAttribute('state', 'expanded');
    //target.querySelector('div[selected]').removeAttribute('selected');
    document.addEventListener('click', dropdown.close)
  },

  baseImput: function() {
    if (dropdown.selected === 'Binary') base.imput = 2;

    if (dropdown.selected === 'Octal') base.imput = 8;

    if (dropdown.selected === 'Decimal') base.imput = 10;

    if (dropdown.selected === 'Duodecimal') base.imput = 12;

    if (dropdown.selected === 'Hexadecimal') base.imput = 16;
  },

  baseOutput: function() {
    if (dropdown.selected === 'Binary') base.output = 2;

    if (dropdown.selected === 'Octal') base.output = 8;

    if (dropdown.selected === 'Decimal') base.output = 10;

    if (dropdown.selected === 'Duodecimal') base.output = 12;

    if (dropdown.selected === 'Hexadecimal') base.output = 16;
  }
};

//---

for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  items[i].addEventListener('click', dropdown.select);
};

for (var i = 0; i < dropdownMenu.length; i++) {
  dropdownMenu[i].addEventListener('click', dropdown.open);
};

// global variables
var calculator = document.querySelector('custom-calculator');
var display = calculator.querySelector('custom-calculator-display');

// storage for the calculator imputs
var memory = [];

// storage for the tempory memory
var memoryTemp = '';

// storage for the result from calculating the memory
var result = '';

// storage for the calculator imputs
var base = {
  imput: 10,
  output: 10
};

// storage for the calculator imputs
var conferter = {
  imput: 1,
  output: 1
};

// reset the calculator
function clear() {
  memory = [];
  result = '';
  display.removeAttribute('state');
};

// remove the last digit in memory
function del() {
  memory.pop();
};

// prosses the keypress
function keyPress(key) {
  // clear if an result is shown and the event hasn't been triggered by the '=' key
  if (result && key !== '=') {
    // reset the calculator
    clear();
  };

  // cicide what action to trigger
  if (key === '=') {
    // calculate the memory
    math();
  } else if (key === 'EFFACER') {
    // delete the last digit
    del();
  } else if (key < base.imput || typeof key == 'string') {
    // add the current key to the memory
    memory.push(key);
  };

  // update the display so it shows the output/result
  update();
};

// calculate the memory
function math() {
  // clear the result
  result = '';

  // loop for amount of items in array
  for (var i = 0; i < memory.length; i++) {
    // check if digit is a nuber
    if (typeof memory[i] == 'number') {
      // add number to storage for memoryTemp
      memoryTemp += memory[i];
    } else {
      // add string to storage for result
      // replace the ร— and the รท to prefent errors
      result += memory[i].replace(/\u00D7/g, '*').replace(/\u00F7/g, '/');
    };

    // check if it should add the content of memoryTemp to result
    if (typeof memory[i + 1] != 'number') {
      // add content memoryTemp to result
      result += parseInt(memoryTemp, base.imput);

      // reset memoryTemp
      memoryTemp = '';
    };
  };

  // test for errors
  try {
    // set eval() result. and confert it to string if it succeeds
    result = eval(result).toString(base.output);
  } catch(err) {
    // set result to err if it fails
    result = 'err';
  };

  // check if result is undefined or the outcome is NaN
  if (result == undefined || result == 'NaN') {
    // set result to err
    result = 'err';
  };

  // set display to [state="result"]
  display.setAttribute('state', 'result');
};

// update the calculator
function update() {
  // set the inner HTML of #output to memory
  display.querySelector('#output').innerHTML = memory.join('');

  // check if there's a '0' at the beginging of the memory
  if (memory[0] == 0) {
    // clear the memory to prefent issues with eval()
    memory = [];
  };

  // check if the result has value undefined
  // check if the result has value 'err'
  if (result === undefined) {
    // reset the calculator
    clear();
  } else if (result === 'err') {
    // set the display to [state="erreur"]
    display.setAttribute('state', 'erreur');

    // set the inner HTML of #output to Error...
    display.querySelector('#output').innerHTML = 'Erreur...';
  } else {
    // set the inner HTML of #result to result
    display.querySelector('#result').innerHTML = result;
  };
};
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=RobotoDraft:100,300,400);
*, *::after, *::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  color: #212121;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1;
}

body {
  background: #fafafa;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  -webkit-transition: opacity ease-in 0.2s;
  transition: opacity ease-in 0.2s;
}
body[unresolved] {
  opacity: 0;
}

::-webkit-selection,
::selection {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

custom-calculator {
  background: #e0e0e0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  font-family: "RobotoDraft", "Roboto", sans-serif;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
  z-index: 500;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  custom-calculator {
    border-radius: 2px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    margin: 16px;
  }
}
custom-calculator-display {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  color: #9e9e9e;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-flex: 5;
  -webkit-flex: 5;
  -ms-flex: 5;
  flex: 5;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-right: 32px;
  position: relative;
}
custom-calculator-display[state="result"] {
  color: #e0e0e0;
}
custom-calculator-display[state="result"] #output {
  font-size: 38px;
  font-weight: 400;
}
custom-calculator-display[state="result"] #result {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}
custom-calculator-display[state="erreur"] {
  background: #F50057;
  color: #e0e0e0;
}

#output {
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-flex: 3;
  -webkit-flex: 3;
      -ms-flex: 3;
          flex: 3;
  font-size: 112px;
  font-weight: 100;
  -webkit-box-pack: end;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-end;
      -ms-flex-pack: end;
          justify-content: flex-end;
  position: relative;
}

#result {
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  display: none;
  -webkit-box-flex: 5;
  -webkit-flex: 5;
      -ms-flex: 5;
          flex: 5;
  font-size: 84px;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
          justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
}
#result::before {
  content: "=";
  font-size: 38px;
  margin-left: 24px;
}

#dropdown {
  display: none;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
          justify-content: space-between;
  height: 56px;
  padding: 4px 0;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  #dropdown {
    height: 64px;
    padding: 8px 0;
  }

  [mode="conferter"] #dropdown {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
  }
}
[primary="red"] custom-calculator-display[state="result"] {
  background: #EF5350;
}

[primary="pink"] custom-calculator-display[state="result"] {
  background: #EC407A;
}

[primary="purple"] custom-calculator-display[state="result"] {
  background: #AB47BC;
}

[primary="deep-purple"] custom-calculator-display[state="result"] {
  background: #7E57C2;
}

[primary="indigo"] custom-calculator-display[state="result"] {
  background: #5C6BC0;
}

[primary="blue"] custom-calculator-display[state="result"] {
  background: #42A5F5;
}

[primary="light-blue"] custom-calculator-display[state="result"] {
  background: #29B6F6;
}

[primary="cyan"] custom-calculator-display[state="result"] {
  background: #26C6DA;
}

[primary="teal"] custom-calculator-display[state="result"] {
  background: #26A69A;
}

[primary="green"] custom-calculator-display[state="result"] {
  background: #66BB6A;
}

[primary="light-green"] custom-calculator-display[state="result"] {
  background: #9CCC65;
}

[primary="lime"] custom-calculator-display[state="result"] {
  background: #D4E157;
}

[primary="yellow"] custom-calculator-display[state="result"] {
  background: #FFEE58;
}

[primary="amber"] custom-calculator-display[state="result"] {
  background: #FFCA28;
}

[primary="orange"] custom-calculator-display[state="result"] {
  background: #FFA726;
}

[primary="deep-orange"] custom-calculator-display[state="result"] {
  background: #FF7043;
}

custom-calculator-drawer {
  box-shadow: -4px 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  position: relative;
  width: 28px;
}

@media (min-width: 784px) {
  custom-calculator-drawer {
    -webkit-box-flex: 3;
    -webkit-flex: 3;
        -ms-flex: 3;
            flex: 3;
  }

  panel-handlebar {
    display: none;
  }
}
panel-handlebar {
  bottom: 0;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  width: 28px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

[accent="red"] custom-calculator-drawer {
  background: #D50000;
}

[accent="pink"] custom-calculator-drawer {
  background: #C51162;
}

[accent="purple"] custom-calculator-drawer {
  background: #AA00FF;
}

[accent="deep-purple"] custom-calculator-drawer {
  background: #6200EA;
}

[accent="indigo"] custom-calculator-drawer {
  background: #304FFE;
}

[accent="blue"] custom-calculator-drawer {
  background: #2962FF;
}

[accent="light-blue"] custom-calculator-drawer {
  background: #0091EA;
}

[accent="cyan"] custom-calculator-drawer {
  background: #00B8D4;
}

[accent="teal"] custom-calculator-drawer {
  background: #00BFA5;
}

[accent="green"] custom-calculator-drawer {
  background: #00C853;
}

[accent="light-green"] custom-calculator-drawer {
  background: #64DD17;
}

[accent="lime"] custom-calculator-drawer {
  background: #AEEA00;
}

[accent="yellow"] custom-calculator-drawer {
  background: #FFD600;
}

[accent="amber"] custom-calculator-drawer {
  background: #FFAB00;
}

[accent="orange"] custom-calculator-drawer {
  background: #FF6D00;
}

[accent="deep-orange"] custom-calculator-drawer {
  background: #DD2C00;
}

custom-calculator-keygrid {
  background: #424242;
  color: #e0e0e0;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-flex: 5;
  -webkit-flex: 5;
      -ms-flex: 5;
          flex: 5;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
      -ms-flex-direction: row;
          flex-direction: row;
  font-size: 34px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

panel-keyrow {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex: 1;
          flex: 1;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
}
panel-keyrow:last-child {
  background: #616161;
  box-shadow: -2px 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  font-size: 32px;
}

custom-calculator-key {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex: 1;
          flex: 1;
  position: relative;
}
custom-calculator-key div {
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  bottom: 0;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

custom-calculator-keypad {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-flex: 8;
  -webkit-flex: 8;
      -ms-flex: 8;
          flex: 8;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
      -ms-flex-direction: row;
          flex-direction: row;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -100;
}

custom-tabs {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  font-size: 20px;
}

panel-tab {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  height: 64px;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
}
panel-tab div {
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex: 1;
          flex: 1;
  margin: 0 24px;
}

[selection-bar] {
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 2px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
[selection-bar][state="expand"] {
  -webkit-transition: 0.15s ease-in;
  transition: 0.15s ease-in;
}
[selection-bar][state="shrink"] {
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

material-dropdown-menu {
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: -webkit-inline-box;
  display: -webkit-inline-flex;
  display: -ms-inline-flexbox;
  display: inline-flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
      -ms-flex-direction: row;
          flex-direction: row;
  height: 48px;
  outline: none;
  position: relative;
  min-width: 168px;
}

#label {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #616161;
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 32px;
  margin: 8px 4px;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
}

material-dropdown {
  background: #fafafa;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  color: #8f8f8f;
  display: none;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0 4px;
  min-height: 64px;
  overflow: visible;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}
material-dropdown div {
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  height: 48px;
  padding: 0 8px;
  width: 100%;
}
material-dropdown div[selected] {
  background: #d6d6d6;
}
material-dropdown div:first-child {
  margin-top: 8px;
}
material-dropdown div:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

[state="expanding"] material-dropdown,
[state="closing"] material-dropdown {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

[state="expanded"] material-dropdown {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

material-selection {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
      -ms-flex-direction: row;
          flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-box-pack: end;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-end;
      -ms-flex-pack: end;
          justify-content: flex-end;
}
material-selection > div {
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  width: 48px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>SIE - Calculette</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
        
        <!-- Styles -->
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href="assets/plugins/pace-master/themes/blue/pace-theme-flash.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link href="assets/plugins/uniform/css/uniform.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link href="assets/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <link href="assets/plugins/fontawesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <link href="assets/plugins/line-icons/simple-line-icons.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/> 
        <link href="assets/plugins/offcanvasmenueffects/css/menu_cornerbox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>  
        <link href="assets/plugins/waves/waves.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>  
        <link href="assets/plugins/switchery/switchery.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <link href="assets/plugins/3d-bold-navigation/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/> 
        <link href="assets/plugins/slidepushmenus/css/component.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    
        <link href="assets/css/modern.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <link href="assets/css/modern.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <link href="assets/css/calculator2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

    
    
    
  </head>

  <body>

    <html primary="light-blue" accent="teal">
  <body>

    <custom-calculator>
      <custom-calculator-display mode="conferter">

        <div id="output">0</div>

        <div id="result"></div>

      </custom-calculator-display>

      <custom-calculator-keypad>
        <custom-calculator-keygrid>
          <panel-keyrow>
            <custom-calculator-key onClick="keyPress(7)">
              <div>7</div>
            </custom-calculator-key>
            <custom-calculator-key onClick="keyPress(4)">
              <div>4</div>
            </custom-calculator-key>
            <custom-calculator-key onClick="keyPress(1)">
              <div>1</div>
            </custom-calculator-key>
            <custom-calculator-key onClick="keyPress('.')">
              <div>.</div>
            </custom-calculator-key>
          </panel-keyrow>
          <panel-keyrow>
            <custom-calculator-key onClick="keyPress(8)">
              <div>8</div>
            </custom-calculator-key>
            <custom-calculator-key onClick="keyPress(5)">
              <div>5</div>
            </custom-calculator-key>
            <custom-calculator-key onClick="keyPress(2)">
              <div>2</div>
            </custom-calculator-key>
            <custom-calculator-key onClick="keyPress(0)">
              <div>0</div>
            </custom-calculator-key>
          </panel-keyrow>
          <panel-keyrow>
            <custom-calculator-key onClick="keyPress(9)">
              <div>9</div>
            </custom-calculator-key>
            <custom-calculator-key onClick="keyPress(6)">
              <div>6</div>
            </custom-calculator-key>
            <custom-calculator-key onClick="keyPress(3)">
              <div>3</div>
            </custom-calculator-key>
            <custom-calculator-key onClick="keyPress('=')">
              <div>=</div>
            </custom-calculator-key>
          </panel-keyrow>
          <panel-keyrow>
            <custom-calculator-key onClick="keyPress('EFFACER')">
              <div>EFFACER</div>
            </custom-calculator-key>
            <custom-calculator-key onClick="keyPress('÷')">
              <div>÷</div>
            </custom-calculator-key>
            <custom-calculator-key onClick="keyPress('×')">
              <div>×</div>
            </custom-calculator-key>
            <custom-calculator-key onClick="keyPress('-')">
              <div>-</div>
            </custom-calculator-key>
            <custom-calculator-key onClick="keyPress('+')">
              <div>+</div>
            </custom-calculator-key>
          </panel-keyrow>
        </custom-calculator-keygrid>

        <custom-calculator-drawer>
          <custom-tabs>
            <panel-tab>
              <div><a href="dashboard.html" style="color:#fff;"><span class="menu-icon glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span>  Accueil</a></div>
            </panel-tab>
            <panel-tab disabeled>
              <div><a href="compta_accueil.html" style="color:#fff;"><span class="menu-icon glyphicon glyphicon-briefcase"></span> Comptabilité</a></div>
            </panel-tab>
            <panel-tab disabeled>
              <div><a href="compta_accueil.html" style="color:#fff;"></a></div>
            </panel-tab>
            <panel-tab disabeled>
              <div><a href="compta_accueil.html" style="color:#fff;"></a></div>
            </panel-tab>
            <panel-tab disabeled>
              <div><a href="compta_accueil.html" style="color:#fff;"></a></div>
            </panel-tab>
            <div class="panel panel-white" style="opacity: 0.9;">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="post">
                        <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Vous pouvez écrire une note depuis ce mini éditeur de texte !" rows="12" style="opacity: 0.9;"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div selection-bar></div>
          </custom-tabs>
          <panel-handlebar></panel-handlebar>
        </custom-calculator-drawer>

      </custom-calculator-keypad>
    </custom-calculator>
  </body>
 </html>
    
        <script src="assets/js/calculator2.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/plugins/jquery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/modern.min.js"></script>
    
    
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your question is hard to understand. I'm guessing you want to use the keyboard to enter numbers instead of clicking the buttons? Use the `onKeyUp` event to find out when the user pressed a key.

Comment: Oups... You guess right !

Answer (score 0):

Even try enabling numeric keypad and check if it helps, here are the steps:

1. Open On-Screen Keyboard by clicking the Start button, clicking All Programs, clicking Accessories, clicking Ease of Access, and then clicking On-Screen Keyboard.
2. Click Options, select the Numeric Keypad check box, and then click OK.